# Calling Fragment from Main Activity adds fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, replace

I am very new to android and I am stuck at calling fragment from main activity . The thing is every time i say to replace() the old framelayout with the new layout it just adds to the original one and does not replaces the view

My activity_main.xml is as :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/splash_screen"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.jaggz.gurudawaraapp.MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splash_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft=" 30dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="300dp"
        android:text="@string/splash_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/splash_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using the above frame layout as container to replace the content for the changing fragments

my code is as :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.app = (App) getApplication().getApplicationContext();



    init();

}


private void init() {
     Fragment frag = new SplashLoginFragment();
     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm1 = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
     ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
     ft1.replace(R.id.container_main, frag);
     ft1.commit();
```

}

and i have a new xml for the SplashLoginFragment 
can anyone help me out

Comment: You shouldn't have an image view and text view in the framelayout. Frame layouts are meant to hold a single component. If you really need a splash ui view, you can do it with visibility toggles or a splash fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` call in `FragmentTransaction` only concerns `Fragments`. It will not touch any other view that happens to be in the container you are adding a `Fragment` to. You have 2 options:

1. Create a separate `ViewGroup` to hold the `SplashLoginFragment`.
2. Remove all views from your `container_main` before committing the transaction.

Comment: and how do i do the first one?

Comment: What first one? What do you mean?